# What is the difference between an kuberntes configuration and a manifest?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops

I am starting with kubernetes and I created my first yaml file to deploy my pod:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tenant-service-deployment
  labels:
    app: tenant-service
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tenant-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tenant-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: tenant-service
          image: cronesharedwesteurope.azurecr.io/tenant-service:dev
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80   
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registrysecret
```

Now I want to get it into azure devops to start - now I read about kubernetes-task and kubernetesmanifest-task and from that I am a bit lost now: Is my file now a configuration or a manifest or is this the same?

Comment: Hi does the explanation from Sibtan help with your issue? If it does, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about [Kubernetes manifest task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes-manifest?view=azure-devops) & [Kubectl task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes?view=azure-devops)

**Kubernetes manifest task**

> Use a Kubernetes manifest task in a build or release pipeline to bake
> and deploy manifests to Kubernetes clusters.

This means that it is used strictly for deploying (`kubectl apply`) manifests to the Kubernetes cluster, you can pass in multiple manifests using this task

```
- task: KubernetesManifest@0
  displayName: Deploy
  inputs:
    kubernetesServiceConnection: someK8sSC1
    namespace: default
    manifests: |
      manifests/deployment.yml
      manifests/service.yml
    imagePullSecrets: |
      some-secret
      some-other-secret
```

**Kubectl task**

> Use this task to deploy, configure, or update a Kubernetes cluster by
> running kubectl commands.

Kubectl task helps you run different kubectl commands (apply, create, delete, exec, expose, get, login, logout, logs, run, set, or top.) on your Kubernetes Cluster. You can run administrative level commands on your cluster as well.

```
- task: Kubernetes@1
  displayName: kubectl apply using arguments
  inputs:
    connectionType: Azure Resource Manager
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
    azureResourceGroup: $(azureResourceGroup)
    kubernetesCluster: $(kubernetesCluster)
    command: apply
    arguments: -f mhc-aks.yaml
```

So in short, if you only need to deploy your manifests, then you should use [Kubernetes manifest task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes-manifest?view=azure-devops)